# Python Scrapy Encoding utf-8

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, scrapy

I have written a program to scrap some data from the web as below.

```
import scrapy

class JPItem(scrapy.Item):
question_content = scrapy.Field()
best_answer = scrapy.Field()

class JPSpider(scrapy.Spider):

name = "jp"
allowed_domains = ['chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp']

def start_requests(self):
    url = 'https://chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/dir/list.php?did=2078297790&flg=1&sort=3&type=list&year=2004&month=1&day=1&page=1'
    yield scrapy.Request(url, self.parse)

def parse(self, response):

    if str(response.css("div.qa-list small::text").extract()) == '条件に一致する質問はみつかりませんでした。':
        for y in range (2004,2007):
            for m in range (1,13):
                for d in range(1,32):
                    url = 'https://chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/dir/list.php?did=2078297790&flg=1&sort=3&type=list&year='+ str(y) + '&month=' + str(m) + '&day=' + str(d) +'&page=1';
                    yield scrapy.Request(url, self.parse)

    else:
        for i in range(0,40):
            url = response.xpath('//ul[@id="qalst"]/li/dl/dt/a/@href')[i].extract()
            yield scrapy.Request(url, self.parse_info)
        next_page = response.css("div.qa-list p.flip a.next::attr(href)").extract_first()
        if next_page is not None:
            yield scrapy.Request(next_page, self.parse)             

def parse_info(self, response):
    item = JPItem()

    item['question_content'] = "\"" + ''.join(response.css("div.mdPstdQstn div.ptsQes p:not([class])").extract() + response.css("div.mdPstdQstn div.ptsQes p.queTxt::text").extract()).replace("\n","\\n").replace("\r","\\r").replace("\t","\\t").replace("<p>","").replace("</p>","").replace("<br>","") + "\""
    item['best_answer'] = "\"" + ''.join(response.css("div.mdPstdBA div.ptsQes p.queTxt::text").extract() + response.css("div.mdPstdBA div.ptsQes p:not([class])").extract()).replace("\n","\\n").replace("\r","\\r").replace("\t","\\t").replace("<p>","").replace("</p>","") + "\""

    yield item
```

I found that there should be a problem with this line

> if str(response.css("div.qa-list small::text").extract()) ==
>   '条件に一致する質問はみつかりませんでした。':

since when I run the program it cannot detect this condition, even if the extracted test should be the equal as stated, it will just skip to the **Else** condition. I have tried to use .encode("utf-8") but it seems could not solve the issue. Would anyone can help to provide some suggestions on this issue?

Greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try `if response.css("div.qa-list small::text").extract_first() == u'条件に一致する質問はみつかりませんでした。':`

Comment: @paultrmbrth just tried that out. It works!

Comment: @paultrmbrth It works perfectly! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As [@paul trmbth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2572383/paul-trmbrth) pointed out, what you are trying to do here is a **compare a list with a string**, which is logically incorrect and would always return `False`. So the options presented are to compare the string with :

- `response.css("div.qa-list small::text").extract_first()` which gives the first extracted element, (here, a string) which is the preferred way since using **extract_first()** avoids an IndexError and returns `None` when it doesn’t find any element matching the selection
- Since extract() returns a list, just doing `response.css("div.qa-list small::text").extract[0]` will work and provide the 1st element.
- And incase you got a list of more than one strings and you want to take all the text together and do some operation with it, a simple method to turn all of them to a single string is to do `''.join(response.css("div.qa-list small::text"))`

In your case using the 1st method is apt, and need not worry about utf-8 conversions as python will handle those internally.